# VBA Copy-Paste According to the condition

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy and paste the values which to another sheet which the countif value is . I mean;

My first sheet name is Product Backlog and Second SheetName is POCOM-Main. I would like to copy the values in POCOM-Main Sheet in Range(A2:A1000) columns to Product Backlog sheet if Range(K2:K1000) value is zero in POCOM-Main K column.I would like to paste the value in last empty row in Product Backlog Sheet Range (A2:A1000).

Comment: You could apply a filter to remove the 0 figures in column K and then copy/paste as normal.

Comment: @Darren Bartup-Cook, I try to do it same way but I could not handle to copy paste it last empty row in another sheet.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have tried please?  It makes it much easier to debug your code or suggest an alternative method if we know what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below maybe? where "ws" is the sheet where the data is being taken from and "sh" is the sheet the data is going to. Please note that this takes zeros as numerical figures.

```
Sub test()
Dim nc As Long, a, b, ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

nc = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=False).Column + 1
a = ws.Range("K1", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
 ReDim b(1 To UBound(a), 1 To 1)
 For i = 2 To UBound(a)

If a(i, 1) <> 0 Then b(i, 1) = 1
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(a), nc)
.Columns(nc).Value = b

On Error Resume Next
.Columns(nc).SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Copy
On Error GoTo 0
End With

sh.Range("A" & sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: nc = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues,
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=False).Column + 1
         is not working

Comment: it should all be on the one line like : nc = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=False).Column + 1